# Standard "view contact" icon

Tags: android, icons, contacts

I'm developing a texting app and would like to create a view contact button. Anyone know what the standard menu icon for such an action is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://design.google.com/icons/

I think you will find an icon which is right for you! ;)